# Why is the width card when accessed on Windows and Macbook Pro different?

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-component, vuetify.js

My code like this :

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-card
          max-width="1000"
          class="mx-auto"
        >

          <v-form v-model="valid">
            <v-container>
              <v-row>
                <v-col
                  cols="12"
                  md="4"
                >
                  <v-text-field
                    label="First name"
                    required
                  ></v-text-field>
                </v-col>

                <v-col
                  cols="12"
                  md="4"
                >
                  <v-text-field
                    label="Last name"
                    required
                  ></v-text-field>
                </v-col>

                <v-col
                  cols="12"
                  md="4"
                >
                  <v-text-field
                    label="E-mail"
                    required
                  ></v-text-field>
                </v-col>
              </v-row>
            </v-container>
          </v-form>

        </v-card>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Demo like this : https://codepen.io/trendingnews/pen/oNgooPg?editors=1010

If accessed by macbook pro like this :

[image]

But if accessed by windows like this :

[image]

It appears the width in windows is bigger

How do I make it the same?

**Note**

I try use Macbook Pro 13 inch 2017

I Install windows in my macbook use bootcamp. So I can see it in macbook and windows

Comment: Not sure, but screen resolution may be different?

Comment: @Aditya Prakash I use the default screen resolution on windows and macbook

Answer (score 0):

Removing the word max from max-width should work.
Max width is the maximum width it can reach.

If it fits without hitting that maximum then it won't stretch the box. (which is what you're seeing on the macbook.)

Comment: Then it's almost certianly because the two screens you are using have different resolutions. However, there is one more option if this is not the case as the code is occasionally interpreted differently between browsers.